# Find if some word from list in text python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-science

I looking for method to find all text that appropriate to value in list:
for example:

```
words =['a', 'ball','hello']
# No. of text:   1                2             3                   4
texts= ["i'm need a answer", "Hi daddy", "hello world", "I love to dance ballet"]
```

The desired result:

1. Shown: because the word "a"
2. Not shown: although having the letter "a", It does not appear as an independent word
3. Shown: because the word "hello"
4. Not Shown: although having the word "ballet", the word "ball" not appear as an independent word

I tried use loop by loop (search if word from words in texts, but without success

Really thank you for your help

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can split your text on whitespace to isolate words. Use the intersection of your splitted texts and the words to find overlap. This function below filters for texts that have an overlapping set of words with the declared word set.

```
def filter_texts(texts):
    words_set = {'a', 'ball', 'hello'}
    filtered = filter(lambda text: set(text.split(' ')) & words_set, texts)
    return list(filtered)

# No. of text:   1                2             3                   4
texts = ["i'm need a answer", "Hi daddy", "hello world", "I love to dance ballet"]
filter_texts(texts)
>> ["i'm need a answer", "hello world"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```py
out = []
for i in texts:
    split = i.split(' ')
    if any((i in split for i in words)):
        out.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
words = ['a', 'ball','hello']
texts = ["i'm need a answer", "Hi daddy", "hello world", "I love to dance ballet"]

for txt in texts:
    if any(w in words for w in txt.split()):
        print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['a', 'ball','hello']
# No. of text:   1                2             3                   4
texts = ["i'm need a answer", "Hi daddy", "hello world", "I love to dance ballet"]

texts_word_lists = []
# build lists of words instead of full text strings
for list_item in texts:
    texts_word_lists.append(list_item.split())
# build a mask of results False
result_mask = [False for x in texts]
# make mask element True if it contains a word
for word in words:
    for index, word_list in enumerate(texts_word_lists):
        if word in word_list:
            result_mask[index] = True
result = []
for mask, text in zip(result_mask, texts):
    if mask:
        result.append(text)
print(result)
```